# is there jquery template count or index?

Tags: jquery, jsp

today, my senior told me to use jquery template. but i don't have any idea of it.
I'd like to use varStatus in jquery template, but i don't know how and i don't know this feature exists.

```
**<!--this is JSTL style loop-->**
<c:forEach var="item" items="${menuItems}" varStatus="status">
<div class="tbtn" data-z_index="${99-status.count}"> //<--This line has loop count
    <div id="${item.m_id}" class="tab_non">
        <div class=left></div>
        <div class=right></div>
        <div class=bg>
            <div class=icon></div>
            <div class=font id=topbutton>${item.m_id}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="close"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</c:forEach>
```

This is jquery-template style loop

```
<script id="topMenuTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
{{if data}}
{{each data}}
<div class="tbtn" data-z_index="${loop??}"> //<--I need to use loop count here too!!
    <div id="${name}" class="tab_non">
        <div class=left></div>
        <div class=right></div>
        <div class=bg>
            <div class=icon></div>
            <div class=font id=topbutton>${name}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="close"></div>
    </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
{{/if}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 1.4.3, you do have access to an `index`:

```
{{each( index, value ) collection}} content {{/each}}
```

Note, the `index` here is just a custom string value you would like to use in place of `index`, but jQuery will default to `$index` for the current index value.

```
<li>
    Title: ${Name}.
    {{each Languages}}
        ${$index + 1}: <em>${$value}. </em>
    {{/each}}
</li>
```

So in your example, you could use the `$index` variable in place of `${loop}`:

```
<div class="tbtn" data-z_index="${index}">
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/